# Connecting points from separate Tikz figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have this code to draw an oscilloscope:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\scl{1}%scaling factor of the picture
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=\scl,
  controlpanels/.style={yellow!30!brown!20!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick},
  screen/.style={green!50!black!60!,draw=black,thick},
  trace/.style={green!60!yellow!40!, ultra thick},
  smallbutton/.style={white,draw=black, thick},
  axes/.style={thick}]
  \fill[green!30!blue!30!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick](0,0)
    rectangle (27.75,13.25);
  \fill[fill=black!40!,draw=black,thick,rounded corners](0.25,0.25) rectangle (27.5,13.00);
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6.5cm,yshift=6.6cm,samples=150, scale=1.1]
    \fill[black!60!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick](-5.3,-5.3) rectangle (5.3,5.3);
    \fill[screen] (-5.0,-5.0) rectangle (5.0,5.0);
    \draw[trace] plot(\x,{1+2.4*sin((2.5*\x +1) r)}); % r for radians...
    \draw[trace] plot(\x,{-1+1.25*sin((0.75*\x) r});
    \draw[thin] (-5.0,-5.0) grid (5.0,5.0);
    \draw[axes] (-5,0)--(5,0); % Time axis
    \draw[axes] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \foreach \i in {-4.8,-4.6,...,4.8} \draw (\i,-0.1)--(\i,0.1);
    \foreach \i in {-4.8,-4.6,...,4.8} \draw (-0.1,\i)--(0.1,\i);
  \end{scope}
  % Feet
  \fill[black!70!,rounded corners,xshift=2cm] (0,-.5) rectangle (2,0);
  \fill[black!70!,rounded corners,xshift=23.75cm] (0,-.5) rectangle (2,0);
  % Lower right panel
  \fill[controlpanels] (12.7,0.5) rectangle (27.1,6.2);
  %Channels
  % CH I
  \draw[thick] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.7cm);
  \fill[gray,draw=black,thick] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.5cm);
  \fill[white,draw=black,thick] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.3cm);%Center1
  \node[scale={1.5*\scl}] at (14.8,2.5) {CH I};
  \draw[thick] (26.0,1.5) circle (0.7cm);
  \fill[gray,draw=black,thick] (26,1.5) circle (0.5cm);
  \fill[white,draw=black,thick] (26,1.5) circle (0.3cm);%Center2
  \node[scale={1.5*\scl}] at (26,2.5) {CH II};
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.8,4.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (14.8,5.5) {Y-pos I};
  \fill[smallbutton] (26.0,4.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (26.0,5.5) {Y-pos II};
  % Volt/div the foreach loop draws the two buttons
  \foreach \i / \b in {18/75,22.5/345}{
  %Second parameter of the loop is the angle of the index mark 
  \begin{scope}[xshift=\i cm,yshift=3.8cm,scale=0.85]
    \node[scale=\scl] at (0,2.3) {Volts/Div};
    \node[scale=\scl,black] at (-1,-2.4) {V};
    \node[scale=\scl,blue]  at (1,-2.4) {mV};
    \clip[rounded corners] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[black!30!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[blue!50!black!20!,draw=black,thick]      (30:1.1)--(30:3)--(3,-3)--(-90:3)--(-90:1.1) arc (-90:30:1.1);
    \draw[very thick,rounded corners](-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1.0);
    \foreach \i in {0,30,...,330}
      \draw[thick] (\i:1.2)--(\i:2.5);
    \foreach \i/\j in {15/50,45/.1,75/.2,105/.5,135/1,165/2,195/5,225/10,255/20,285/5,315/10,345/20} \node[scale=\scl,black] at (\i:1.7) {\j};
    \fill[blue!30!black!60!,draw=black,thick] (0,0) circle (0.8cm);
    % Here you set the right Volts/Div button
    \draw[ultra thick,red] (\b:0.3)--(\b:1.2);
  \end{scope}}
% Upper right panel
  \fill[controlpanels] (12.7,6.5) rectangle (27.1,12.75);
  %On-Off button
%  \draw[rounded corners,thick,blue] (13.9,10.5) rectangle (15.9,12.5);
  \fill[fill=red,draw=black,thick,rounded corners] (14.4,10.8) rectangle (15.3,11.2);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.8,12) {\textbf{Power}};
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.8,11.5) {\textbf{On/Off}};
  % Focus-Intensity buttons
  %\draw[rounded corners,thick,blue] (13.9,7.0) rectangle (15.9,10.0);
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.9,7.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.9,8.2) {\textbf{Focus}};
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.9,9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.9,9.6) {\textbf{Intens}};
  % X-pos
  \fill[smallbutton] (24.5,9.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (24.5,10.5) {X-pos};
  % Time/Div
  \begin{scope}[xshift=21cm,yshift=9.5cm,scale=1]
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}]  at (0,2.4) {Time/Div};
    \clip[rounded corners] (-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \fill[black!30!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick] (-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \fill[blue!50!black!20!,draw=black,thick] (45:1.1)--(45:3)--(3,-3)--(-90:3)--(-90:1.1) arc (-90:45:1.1);
    \fill[green!50!black!40!,draw=black,thick]
      (45:1.1)--(45:3) arc(45:207:3) --(207:1.1) arc (207:45:1.1);
    \draw[very thick,rounded corners](-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (-1.6,-1.6) {$s$};
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (1.6,-1.6) {$\mu{}\,s$};
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (-1.6,1.6) {$m\,s$};
    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1.0);
    \foreach \i in {-72,-54,...,262} \draw[thick] (\i:1.15)--(\i:1.35);
    \foreach \i/\j in {-72/.5,-54/1,-36/2,-18/5,0/10,18/20,36/50,54/.1,72/.2,90/.5,108/1,126/2,144/5,162/10,180/20,198/50,216/.1,234/.2,252/.5}
      \node[scale=\scl,black] at (\i:1.7){\j};
    \fill[blue!30!black!60!,draw=black,thick] (0,0) circle (0.8cm);
    % Here you set the Time/Div button
    \draw[ultra thick,red] (-18:0.3)--(-18:1.2);    
    % X-pos
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It has two channels (I and II). I want to make a diagram with multiple oscilloscopes showing where they are all connected. It is possible to use the same code on Tikz multiple times and connect a point in the first picture to a point on another one? For example, can I do something as shown below?

[image]

Comment: You can use ‘remember picture’ to remember the coordinates and then ‘overlay,remember picture’ to connect them.

Comment: The only problem is that you need to use different coordinate names for different oscilloscopes.  Alas, a savebox won't do the trick.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a possible way.

1. Name the coordinates you want to connect. I did that for `CH I`.
2. Add `remember picture` in the `tikzpicture`s.
3. Give each `tikzpicture` a different `name prefix`. This is needed to give the coordinates unique names (cf. [John Kormylo's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506407/connecting-points-from-separate-tikz-figures#comment1279368_506407)). To simplify things I created a macro that does the picture and has the name prefix as its argument.
4. Connect the coordinates in a `tikzpicture` with options `overlay, remember picture`. The coordinates will have names `(<prefix><name specified>)`. The following contains one example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\scl{0.25}%scaling factor of the picture
\newcommand{\Oscilloscope}[2][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[name prefix=#2,remember picture,#1,
  scale=\scl,
  controlpanels/.style={yellow!30!brown!20!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick},
  screen/.style={green!50!black!60!,draw=black,thick},
  trace/.style={green!60!yellow!40!, ultra thick},
  smallbutton/.style={white,draw=black, thick},
  axes/.style={thick}]
  \fill[green!30!blue!30!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick](0,0)
    rectangle (27.75,13.25);
  \fill[fill=black!40!,draw=black,thick,rounded corners](0.25,0.25) rectangle (27.5,13.00);
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6.5cm,yshift=6.6cm,samples=150, scale=1.1]
    \fill[black!60!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick](-5.3,-5.3) rectangle (5.3,5.3);
    \fill[screen] (-5.0,-5.0) rectangle (5.0,5.0);
    \draw[trace] plot(\x,{1+2.4*sin((2.5*\x +1) r)}); % r for radians...
    \draw[trace] plot(\x,{-1+1.25*sin((0.75*\x) r});
    \draw[thin] (-5.0,-5.0) grid (5.0,5.0);
    \draw[axes] (-5,0)--(5,0); % Time axis
    \draw[axes] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \foreach \i in {-4.8,-4.6,...,4.8} \draw (\i,-0.1)--(\i,0.1);
    \foreach \i in {-4.8,-4.6,...,4.8} \draw (-0.1,\i)--(0.1,\i);
  \end{scope}
  % Feet
  \fill[black!70!,rounded corners,xshift=2cm] (0,-.5) rectangle (2,0);
  \fill[black!70!,rounded corners,xshift=23.75cm] (0,-.5) rectangle (2,0);
  % Lower right panel
  \fill[controlpanels] (12.7,0.5) rectangle (27.1,6.2);
  %Channels
  % CH I
  \draw[thick] (14.8,1.5) coordinate(CH I) circle (0.7cm);
  \fill[gray,draw=black,thick] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.5cm);
  \fill[white,draw=black,thick] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.3cm);%Center1
  \node[scale={1.5*\scl}] at (14.8,2.5) {CH I};
  \draw[thick] (26.0,1.5) circle (0.7cm);
  \fill[gray,draw=black,thick] (26,1.5) circle (0.5cm);
  \fill[white,draw=black,thick] (26,1.5) circle (0.3cm);%Center2
  \node[scale={1.5*\scl}] at (26,2.5) {CH II};
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.8,4.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (14.8,5.5) {Y-pos I};
  \fill[smallbutton] (26.0,4.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (26.0,5.5) {Y-pos II};
  % Volt/div the foreach loop draws the two buttons
  \foreach \i / \b in {18/75,22.5/345}{
  %Second parameter of the loop is the angle of the index mark 
  \begin{scope}[xshift=\i cm,yshift=3.8cm,scale=0.85]
    \node[scale=\scl] at (0,2.3) {Volts/Div};
    \node[scale=\scl,black] at (-1,-2.4) {V};
    \node[scale=\scl,blue]  at (1,-2.4) {mV};
    \clip[rounded corners] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[black!30!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[blue!50!black!20!,draw=black,thick]      (30:1.1)--(30:3)--(3,-3)--(-90:3)--(-90:1.1) arc (-90:30:1.1);
    \draw[very thick,rounded corners](-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1.0);
    \foreach \i in {0,30,...,330}
      \draw[thick] (\i:1.2)--(\i:2.5);
    \foreach \i/\j in {15/50,45/.1,75/.2,105/.5,135/1,165/2,195/5,225/10,255/20,285/5,315/10,345/20} \node[scale=\scl,black] at (\i:1.7) {\j};
    \fill[blue!30!black!60!,draw=black,thick] (0,0) circle (0.8cm);
    % Here you set the right Volts/Div button
    \draw[ultra thick,red] (\b:0.3)--(\b:1.2);
  \end{scope}}
% Upper right panel
  \fill[controlpanels] (12.7,6.5) rectangle (27.1,12.75);
  %On-Off button
%  \draw[rounded corners,thick,blue] (13.9,10.5) rectangle (15.9,12.5);
  \fill[fill=red,draw=black,thick,rounded corners] (14.4,10.8) rectangle (15.3,11.2);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.8,12) {\textbf{Power}};
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.8,11.5) {\textbf{On/Off}};
  % Focus-Intensity buttons
  %\draw[rounded corners,thick,blue] (13.9,7.0) rectangle (15.9,10.0);
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.9,7.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.9,8.2) {\textbf{Focus}};
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.9,9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.9,9.6) {\textbf{Intens}};
  % X-pos
  \fill[smallbutton] (24.5,9.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (24.5,10.5) {X-pos};
  % Time/Div
  \begin{scope}[xshift=21cm,yshift=9.5cm,scale=1]
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}]  at (0,2.4) {Time/Div};
    \clip[rounded corners] (-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \fill[black!30!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick] (-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \fill[blue!50!black!20!,draw=black,thick] (45:1.1)--(45:3)--(3,-3)--(-90:3)--(-90:1.1) arc (-90:45:1.1);
    \fill[green!50!black!40!,draw=black,thick]
      (45:1.1)--(45:3) arc(45:207:3) --(207:1.1) arc (207:45:1.1);
    \draw[very thick,rounded corners](-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (-1.6,-1.6) {$s$};
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (1.6,-1.6) {$\mu{}\,s$};
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (-1.6,1.6) {$m\,s$};
    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1.0);
    \foreach \i in {-72,-54,...,262} \draw[thick] (\i:1.15)--(\i:1.35);
    \foreach \i/\j in {-72/.5,-54/1,-36/2,-18/5,0/10,18/20,36/50,54/.1,72/.2,90/.5,108/1,126/2,144/5,162/10,180/20,198/50,216/.1,234/.2,252/.5}
      \node[scale=\scl,black] at (\i:1.7){\j};
    \fill[blue!30!black!60!,draw=black,thick] (0,0) circle (0.8cm);
    % Here you set the Time/Div button
    \draw[ultra thick,red] (-18:0.3)--(-18:1.2);    
    % X-pos
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\Oscilloscope{L-}~~~\Oscilloscope{R-}\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[very thick] (L-CH I) to[bend right] (R-CH I);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You need to compile twice.

**ADDENDUM**: As for your request in the comments: I stored the angles of the channels I and II in pgf keys whose default values match the above. In the extended version, you can set these keys in the optional argument of the command, e.g.

```
\Oscilloscope[oscilloscope/channel 1=135,oscilloscope/channel 2=225]{R-}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{oscilloscope/.cd,channel 1/.initial=75,channel 2/.initial=345}
\begin{document}
\def\scl{0.25}%scaling factor of the picture
\newcommand{\Oscilloscope}[2][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[name prefix=#2,remember picture,#1,
  scale=\scl,
  controlpanels/.style={yellow!30!brown!20!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick},
  screen/.style={green!50!black!60!,draw=black,thick},
  trace/.style={green!60!yellow!40!, ultra thick},
  smallbutton/.style={white,draw=black, thick},
  axes/.style={thick}]
  \fill[green!30!blue!30!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick](0,0)
    rectangle (27.75,13.25);
  \fill[fill=black!40!,draw=black,thick,rounded corners](0.25,0.25) rectangle (27.5,13.00);
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6.5cm,yshift=6.6cm,samples=150, scale=1.1]
    \fill[black!60!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick](-5.3,-5.3) rectangle (5.3,5.3);
    \fill[screen] (-5.0,-5.0) rectangle (5.0,5.0);
    \draw[trace] plot(\x,{1+2.4*sin((2.5*\x +1) r)}); % r for radians...
    \draw[trace] plot(\x,{-1+1.25*sin((0.75*\x) r});
    \draw[thin] (-5.0,-5.0) grid (5.0,5.0);
    \draw[axes] (-5,0)--(5,0); % Time axis
    \draw[axes] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \foreach \i in {-4.8,-4.6,...,4.8} \draw (\i,-0.1)--(\i,0.1);
    \foreach \i in {-4.8,-4.6,...,4.8} \draw (-0.1,\i)--(0.1,\i);
  \end{scope}
  % Feet
  \fill[black!70!,rounded corners,xshift=2cm] (0,-.5) rectangle (2,0);
  \fill[black!70!,rounded corners,xshift=23.75cm] (0,-.5) rectangle (2,0);
  % Lower right panel
  \fill[controlpanels] (12.7,0.5) rectangle (27.1,6.2);
  %Channels
  % CH I
  \draw[thick] (14.8,1.5) coordinate(CH I) circle (0.7cm);
  \fill[gray,draw=black,thick] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.5cm);
  \fill[white,draw=black,thick] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.3cm);%Center1
  \node[scale={1.5*\scl}] at (14.8,2.5) {CH I};
  \draw[thick] (26.0,1.5) circle (0.7cm);
  \fill[gray,draw=black,thick] (26,1.5) circle (0.5cm);
  \fill[white,draw=black,thick] (26,1.5) circle (0.3cm);%Center2
  \node[scale={1.5*\scl}] at (26,2.5) {CH II};
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.8,4.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (14.8,5.5) {Y-pos I};
  \fill[smallbutton] (26.0,4.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (26.0,5.5) {Y-pos II};
  % Volt/div the foreach loop draws the two buttons
  \foreach \i [count=\k] in {18,22.5}{
  %Second parameter of the loop is the angle of the index mark 
  \begin{scope}[xshift=\i cm,yshift=3.8cm,scale=0.85]
    \node[scale=\scl] at (0,2.3) {Volts/Div};
    \node[scale=\scl,black] at (-1,-2.4) {V};
    \node[scale=\scl,blue]  at (1,-2.4) {mV};
    \clip[rounded corners] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[black!30!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[blue!50!black!20!,draw=black,thick]      (30:1.1)--(30:3)--(3,-3)--(-90:3)--(-90:1.1) arc (-90:30:1.1);
    \draw[very thick,rounded corners](-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1.0);
    \foreach \i in {0,30,...,330}
      \draw[thick] (\i:1.2)--(\i:2.5);
    \foreach \i/\j in {15/50,45/.1,75/.2,105/.5,135/1,165/2,195/5,225/10,255/20,285/5,315/10,345/20} \node[scale=\scl,black] at (\i:1.7) {\j};
    \fill[blue!30!black!60!,draw=black,thick] (0,0) circle (0.8cm);
    % Here you set the right Volts/Div button
    \draw[ultra thick,red] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/oscilloscope/channel \k}:0.3)
    --(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/oscilloscope/channel \k}:1.2);
  \end{scope}}
% Upper right panel
  \fill[controlpanels] (12.7,6.5) rectangle (27.1,12.75);
  %On-Off button
%  \draw[rounded corners,thick,blue] (13.9,10.5) rectangle (15.9,12.5);
  \fill[fill=red,draw=black,thick,rounded corners] (14.4,10.8) rectangle (15.3,11.2);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.8,12) {\textbf{Power}};
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.8,11.5) {\textbf{On/Off}};
  % Focus-Intensity buttons
  %\draw[rounded corners,thick,blue] (13.9,7.0) rectangle (15.9,10.0);
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.9,7.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.9,8.2) {\textbf{Focus}};
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.9,9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.9,9.6) {\textbf{Intens}};
  % X-pos
  \fill[smallbutton] (24.5,9.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (24.5,10.5) {X-pos};
  % Time/Div
  \begin{scope}[xshift=21cm,yshift=9.5cm,scale=1]
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}]  at (0,2.4) {Time/Div};
    \clip[rounded corners] (-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \fill[black!30!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick] (-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \fill[blue!50!black!20!,draw=black,thick] (45:1.1)--(45:3)--(3,-3)--(-90:3)--(-90:1.1) arc (-90:45:1.1);
    \fill[green!50!black!40!,draw=black,thick]
      (45:1.1)--(45:3) arc(45:207:3) --(207:1.1) arc (207:45:1.1);
    \draw[very thick,rounded corners](-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (-1.6,-1.6) {$s$};
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (1.6,-1.6) {$\mu{}\,s$};
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (-1.6,1.6) {$m\,s$};
    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1.0);
    \foreach \i in {-72,-54,...,262} \draw[thick] (\i:1.15)--(\i:1.35);
    \foreach \i/\j in {-72/.5,-54/1,-36/2,-18/5,0/10,18/20,36/50,54/.1,72/.2,90/.5,108/1,126/2,144/5,162/10,180/20,198/50,216/.1,234/.2,252/.5}
      \node[scale=\scl,black] at (\i:1.7){\j};
    \fill[blue!30!black!60!,draw=black,thick] (0,0) circle (0.8cm);
    % Here you set the Time/Div button
    \draw[ultra thick,red] (-18:0.3)--(-18:1.2);    
    % X-pos
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\Oscilloscope{L-}~~~\Oscilloscope[oscilloscope/channel 1=135,%
oscilloscope/channel 2=225]{R-}\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[very thick] (L-CH I) to[bend right] (R-CH I);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this is a *start*. You can store many more parameters in pgf keys, and also simplify the code quite a bit.

**ADDENDUM**: You may also want to make things more Ti*k*Zy by making the oscilloscope a pic. Then the name prefix is given by its name, see the example on p. 262 of pgfmanual v3.1.4. This allows you to position the oscilloscopes more easily relative to each other, e.g. using a `\matrix` (which works with `pic`s, too). This way the bent line is not an overlay picture, and you get the (more or less) appropriate bounding box automatically.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{oscilloscope/.cd,channel 1/.initial=75,channel 2/.initial=345,
scale/.initial=0.25,
/tikz/pics/oscilloscope/.style={code={\begin{scope}[scale=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/oscilloscope/scale}]
 \def\scl{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/oscilloscope/scale}}
 \tikzset{oscilloscope/.cd,#1}
  \fill[green!30!blue!30!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick](0,0)
    rectangle (27.75,13.25);
  \fill[fill=black!40!,draw=black,thick,rounded corners](0.25,0.25) rectangle (27.5,13.00);
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6.5cm,yshift=6.6cm,samples=150, scale=1.1]
    \fill[black!60!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick](-5.3,-5.3) rectangle (5.3,5.3);
    \fill[screen] (-5.0,-5.0) rectangle (5.0,5.0);
    \draw[trace] plot(\x,{1+2.4*sin((2.5*\x +1) r)}); % r for radians...
    \draw[trace] plot(\x,{-1+1.25*sin((0.75*\x) r});
    \draw[thin] (-5.0,-5.0) grid (5.0,5.0);
    \draw[axes] (-5,0)--(5,0); % Time axis
    \draw[axes] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \foreach \i in {-4.8,-4.6,...,4.8} \draw (\i,-0.1)--(\i,0.1);
    \foreach \i in {-4.8,-4.6,...,4.8} \draw (-0.1,\i)--(0.1,\i);
  \end{scope}
  % Feet
  \fill[black!70!,rounded corners,xshift=2cm] (0,-.5) rectangle (2,0);
  \fill[black!70!,rounded corners,xshift=23.75cm] (0,-.5) rectangle (2,0);
  % Lower right panel
  \fill[controlpanels] (12.7,0.5) rectangle (27.1,6.2);
  %Channels
  % CH I
  \draw[thick] (14.8,1.5) coordinate(-CH I) circle (0.7cm);
  \fill[gray,draw=black,thick] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.5cm);
  \fill[white,draw=black,thick] (14.8,1.5) circle (0.3cm);%Center1
  \node[scale={1.5*\scl}] at (14.8,2.5) {CH I};
  \draw[thick] (26.0,1.5) coordinate(-CH II) circle (0.7cm);
  \fill[gray,draw=black,thick] (26,1.5) circle (0.5cm);
  \fill[white,draw=black,thick] (26,1.5) circle (0.3cm);%Center2
  \node[scale={1.5*\scl}] at (26,2.5) {CH II};
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.8,4.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (14.8,5.5) {Y-pos I};
  \fill[smallbutton] (26.0,4.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (26.0,5.5) {Y-pos II};
  % Volt/div the foreach loop draws the two buttons
  \foreach \i [count=\k] in {18,22.5}{
  %Second parameter of the loop is the angle of the index mark 
  \begin{scope}[xshift=\i cm,yshift=3.8cm,scale=0.85]
    \node[scale=\scl] at (0,2.3) {Volts/Div};
    \node[scale=\scl,black] at (-1,-2.4) {V};
    \node[scale=\scl,blue]  at (1,-2.4) {mV};
    \clip[rounded corners] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[black!30!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[blue!50!black!20!,draw=black,thick]      (30:1.1)--(30:3)--(3,-3)--(-90:3)--(-90:1.1) arc (-90:30:1.1);
    \draw[very thick,rounded corners](-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1.0);
    \foreach \i in {0,30,...,330}
      \draw[thick] (\i:1.2)--(\i:2.5);
    \foreach \i/\j in {15/50,45/.1,75/.2,105/.5,135/1,165/2,195/5,225/10,255/20,285/5,315/10,345/20} \node[scale=\scl,black] at (\i:1.7) {\j};
    \fill[blue!30!black!60!,draw=black,thick] (0,0) circle (0.8cm);
    % Here you set the right Volts/Div button
    \draw[ultra thick,red] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/oscilloscope/channel \k}:0.3)
    --(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/oscilloscope/channel \k}:1.2);
  \end{scope}}
% Upper right panel
  \fill[controlpanels] (12.7,6.5) rectangle (27.1,12.75);
  %On-Off button
%  \draw[rounded corners,thick,blue] (13.9,10.5) rectangle (15.9,12.5);
  \fill[fill=red,draw=black,thick,rounded corners] (14.4,10.8) rectangle (15.3,11.2);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.8,12) {\textbf{Power}};
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.8,11.5) {\textbf{On/Off}};
  % Focus-Intensity buttons
  %\draw[rounded corners,thick,blue] (13.9,7.0) rectangle (15.9,10.0);
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.9,7.5) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.9,8.2) {\textbf{Focus}};
  \fill[smallbutton] (14.9,9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale=\scl] at (14.9,9.6) {\textbf{Intens}};
  % X-pos
  \fill[smallbutton] (24.5,9.9) circle (0.3cm);
  \node[scale={\scl}] at (24.5,10.5) {X-pos};
  % Time/Div
  \begin{scope}[xshift=21cm,yshift=9.5cm,scale=1]
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}]  at (0,2.4) {Time/Div};
    \clip[rounded corners] (-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \fill[black!30!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick] (-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \fill[blue!50!black!20!,draw=black,thick] (45:1.1)--(45:3)--(3,-3)--(-90:3)--(-90:1.1) arc (-90:45:1.1);
    \fill[green!50!black!40!,draw=black,thick]
      (45:1.1)--(45:3) arc(45:207:3) --(207:1.1) arc (207:45:1.1);
    \draw[very thick,rounded corners](-2.2,-2) rectangle (2.2,2);
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (-1.6,-1.6) {$s$};
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (1.6,-1.6) {$\mu{}\,s$};
    \node[scale={1.25*\scl}] at (-1.6,1.6) {$m\,s$};
    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1.0);
    \foreach \i in {-72,-54,...,262} \draw[thick] (\i:1.15)--(\i:1.35);
    \foreach \i/\j in {-72/.5,-54/1,-36/2,-18/5,0/10,18/20,36/50,54/.1,72/.2,90/.5,108/1,126/2,144/5,162/10,180/20,198/50,216/.1,234/.2,252/.5}
      \node[scale=\scl,black] at (\i:1.7){\j};
    \fill[blue!30!black!60!,draw=black,thick] (0,0) circle (0.8cm);
    % Here you set the Time/Div button
    \draw[ultra thick,red] (-18:0.3)--(-18:1.2);    
    % X-pos
  \end{scope}
\end{scope}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[controlpanels/.style={yellow!30!brown!20!,rounded corners,draw=black,thick},
  screen/.style={green!50!black!60!,draw=black,thick},
  trace/.style={green!60!yellow!40!, ultra thick},
  smallbutton/.style={white,draw=black, thick},
  axes/.style={thick}]
  \matrix[column sep=3mm] {
  \pic (L) {oscilloscope}; & \pic (R) {oscilloscope={channel 1=135,channel 2=225}};\\
  };
 \draw[very thick] (L-CH I) to[bend right] (R-CH I);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks great :) Can I configure each scope individually? Say, set the knobs in the one on the left in one position and the knobs in the one on the right in another.

Comment: @Rodrigo Yes. I added a version that has this possibility.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat what is parameter #2?  Thanks

Comment: @jpayansomet This is the name prefix to make the coordinates unique.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat thanks, but I don't understand where is the parameter passed

Comment: @jpayansomet  It is the line `\begin{tikzpicture}[name prefix=#2,remember picture,#1`. I added an arguably better version using `pic`s.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, thanks. Now I understand it better than before. It's very nice!!!